# Ajax function not receiving response from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

Essentially I am working with an uploader (`dropzone.js`) and incorporating it into my website. Adding files to the server works fine, I am however having trouble with deleting them. My JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = true;
    $("#dZUpload").dropzone({
        url: "uploadHandler.ashx",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        success: function (file, response) {
            file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
            console.log("Successfully uploaded: " + file.name);
        },
        error: function (file, response) {
            file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
        },
        init: function () {
            var dZUpload = this;
            this.on("removedfile", function (file) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "uploadHandler.ashx/DeleteFile",
                    data: { filename: file.name },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (repsonse) {
                        if (data == "success") {
                            alert("Successfully deleted.");
                            this.removeFile(file);
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Error deleting file.");
                            this.removeFile(file);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }

    });
});
```

and this is code for the `deleteFile` function on my server-side handler:

```
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Function DeleteFile(filename As String) As String
    Try
        Dim Yes As String = "success"
        System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/serverFiles/"), filename))
        Return Yes
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim No As String = "failure"
        Return No
    End Try
End Function
```

What should be happening: When the remove link is clicked on an uploaded file, the client sends a `POST` through `Ajax` to the server. The server than deletes the file off the disk and sends a message to the client saying it was a success.

This is my first time using Ajax, what is happening? Why isn't the message being sent?

Edit: When I change `dataType: "json"` to `test` I reeive the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
$.ajax.success @ fileUploader.aspx:31
```

Line 31 is this: `if (data == "success") {`

So its a little better but I'm still not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Any error messages in console log or server side?

Comment: please use error, complete methods and put some logs to check the error,if it is reaching error block there some error, complete will be called in both the cases

Comment: @MatthewNorth no errors on both the client side and the server side, its almost as if the Ajax isn't being processed below the following line `$.ajax({` (line 16 in the fist code snippet)

Comment: Try changing type: "POST" to method: "POST" and see if that helps

Comment: Additionally you can try changing
data: file.name to data: JSON.stringify({ filename: file.name }),
and add contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Comment: @MatthewNorth I've added your changes but I am still receiving the same error that I posted above.

Comment: Make your web method shared (I'm no expert in VB but they need to be static in C#), I also updated the json.stringify above if you didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

Declare your Web Method as shared (static) e.g.

```
    Public Shared Function DeleteFile(filename As String) As String
```

and then modify your AJAX call to:

```
    var data = { filename: file.name }
    $.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         url: "uploadHandler.ashx/DeleteFile",
         data: JSON.stringify(data),
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function (repsonse) {
             if (data == "success") {
                 alert("Successfully deleted.");
                 this.removeFile(file);
             }
             else {
                 alert("Error deleting file.");
                 this.removeFile(file);
             }
         }
    });
```

Comment: I've done those changes and I've found another change `function(response)` needs to be `function(data)`. For whatever reason my DeleteFile function is not being called. Any idea why that's happening? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Can you check the console log on the browser and check what url is being called? everything else looks correct with the AJAX call,

Comment: `Request URL: http://localhost:14470/WebSite2/uploadHandler.ashx/DeleteFile` return status is OK as well. Is everything okay with my handler?

Comment: .net still wont know how to handle the json structure when you get it back, you cant just call "Server.MapPath("~/serverFiles/"), filename" and expect it to get the correct data